# Apache Ignite: How to get events for a specific cache

Tags: c#, ignite, gridgain

I have two caches configured in ignite and I need to get the events  CacheObjectPut & CacheObjectRemoved specific to one cache.
When I tried with the below-mentioned steps, I am getting events for all caches.
Let me know how to get the events only for a specific cache?

```
var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
{
    IncludedEventTypes = new[]
    {
        EventType.CacheObjectPut,
        EventType.CacheObjectRemoved,
    }
};
var ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg);

var events = ignite.GetEvents();
events.LocalListen(new LocalListener(), EventType.CacheObjectPut,        EventType.CacheObjectRemoved);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're better off using [Continuous Queries](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.Query.Continuous.html) rather than events. CQs also work against a specific cache.